# Why there is no patchForEntity method just like postForEntity in RestTemplate?

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot, controller, resttemplate

I would like to know why there is no `patchForEntity` method provided in `RestTemplate` class same like `postForEntity` and `getForEntity`. Only `patchForObject` method is there which only returns the object but not the `ResponseEntity`.

To get the `ResponseEntity` for a `PATCH` request, we have to use the `exchange` method of `RestTemplate`, which is OK, but I am really curious why the Spring guys haven't provided a handy `patchForEntity` method.

Any clue?

Answer (score 2):

A similar issue has been opened in [Spring's GitHub](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/23228). To quote from the answer that was given there:

> ... While it would be technically possible to introduce a `patchForEntity()` method, analogous to the existing `getForEntity()` and `postForEntity()` methods, there are no plans to introduce new functionality in the `RestTemplate` API ...

So, to answer your question, there seems to be no technical reason why this functionality wasn't provided, just that the priority to do so wasn't high enough, since, as you mentioned in your question, you can achieve the effect you want using the `exchange` method. Anyway (and this was news to me), *"there are no plans to introduce new functionality in the RestTemplate API"* because it's going to be deprecated in favor of `WebClient`, so odds are `RestTemplate`  will *never* have the `patchForEntity()` method.